# input{file} for local file not found

Tags: input

I have a .tex file which tries to input another local file:

```
%!TEX root = ../rings.tex
\pagebreak
\chapter{Analisis}
\input{toLatex}
```

Both files `analisis.tex` and `toLatex.tex` reside in the same folder:

```
$latex/01_analisis$ ll
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 lucas lucas 4096 abr 13 12:30 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 lucas lucas 4096 abr 13 12:41 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lucas lucas  130 abr 13 12:41 analisis.tex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lucas lucas 9919 abr 13 12:37 toLatex.tex
```

However, when I try to get the pdf (I'm using Sublime-text) I get an error message saying `toLatex` cannot be found.

```
[Compiling latex/rings.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking latexmk... done.

Errors:

latex/01_analisis/analisis.tex:11: LaTeX Error: File `toLatex.tex' not found. [\input{toLatex}]
```

It's weird because in the main.tex file I'm already using the `\input{}` command and it's working.

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\def\contentsname{Indice}
\tableofcontents{}
\def\listfigurename{Figuras}
\listoffigures
\def\listtablename{Tablas} 
\listoftables

\input{00_intro/intro}
\input{01_analisis/analisis}

\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Any hint? thanks!

Comment: looking at your sketch I assume you need `\input{01_analisis/toLatex}` the paths are relative to the working directory of the tex process

Comment: thanks ... this solved it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
 \input{01_analisis/toLatex}
```

the paths are relative to the working directory of the tex process, not to the file in which the `\inout` command appears.